Black on insulation paper
Noticed this area of dark black on the insulation paper. The wood and the insulation itself look fine. Is that just the tar paper/vapor barrier showing through? Mold?
https://imgur.com/a/b18a1p3

Mold needs to be tested to tell.  Possible it is mold or paint/ink/something spilled on it.  Mold usually likes moisture/damp conditions.

if you can't tell what it is, then how do you expect someone else to tell from just a picture? ... you can actually examine it closely, nobody else on the internet can

@jsotola Because maybe someone more knowledgeable than me knows the answer? Hence why I asked...

only someone that can make a close examination would know the answer ... hire someone more knowledgeable than you

I have seen spots similar on the paper facing of insulation. It could be from ink used in printing on the paper, or an abundance of glue used to stick the paper to the insulation. It would be very odd for mold to grow like that.
Additionally, there is nothing surrounding the area that indicates moisture that would be needed for mold to grow.  You can relax.

thanks so much.
